# How to set the maximum width for div's content which consists of images and text

Tags: html, css

How can I set the maximum width for `div`'s content (images and text) so it can shrink accordingly?

https://jsfiddle.net/5tav89hw/3/

The expected behavior -- image shrinked to the 50px width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reset display of `<a>` to block and `img`'s width to 100%

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5tav89hw/4/)

```
a {
  display:block;
}
a img {
  width:100%;
}
```

[container turned to 150px](https://jsfiddle.net/5tav89hw/5/)

Comment: You can also set an explicit width (like `width: 300px;`) and add a max-width property (`max-width: 100%;`) if you only want the image to scale up to a certain size.

Comment: @BrianD max-width is plenty enough indeed ;)

Comment: Why should I set `display:block` for the `a` tag? And why does `width:100%` help anyway?

Comment: @FrozenHeart  does it help ?  inline element is just like text, it doesn't hold anything , set to block, it takes all width avalaible. for child this width is 100%. Block is just there to make sure it works and that the tag a is able to inherit populate styles to childs. it is actually  quiet basic behavior :) even if you are not familiar with it yet

Comment: "does it help ?" -- yes, thanks a lot, will accept your answer. btw do you know how to place all `container`'s content horizontally in the center?

Comment: @FrozenHeart you mean the container itself ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I mean all `container`'s stuff. Actually, all of the elements in the provided example

Comment: Thanks a lot! How to do it for the `thread` div too? Just setting `margin: auto` there doesn't seem to work

Comment: @FrozenHeart your padding is in the way, box-shadow added so you see where it stands https://jsfiddle.net/5tav89hw/8/

Comment: So, I just need to remove `padding` and it'll place it in the center horizontally because of the `text-align: center` style of the `container` element, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100523/discussion-between-frozenheart-and-gcyrillus).

Answer (score 1):

You can {width: auto} or {width: 100% }